# cannot Create MD5 FingerPrint?

Tags: android, google-api

keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore

using above command when i try to create md5 fingerprint
it asks for the password and in password i cannot type any thing.

can any one guide me how can i create this i need this finger print to run google map api in android and to obtain googlemap api key from google website..

any help would be appriciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i got my answer,

command above i was using was not complete i just used this command

keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore D:\Androidkeystore\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

if you have not set environment variables for java in your machine then above command wont work or you will have to go to the bin directy of your java folder in program files to run above command.

by copy pasting debug.keystore file from builtin folder to user friendly folder and ran it.

and finally i got the md5 certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can type a password, it just isn't being shown — even as asterisks — for security reasons.

The idea is that someone watching over your shoulder could gain information (i.e. the password length), so showing nothing improves security (slightly, in theory).